# Show that kernel is $\langle p(x)\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> **Question**: Let $F$ be a field and $p(x)$ is irreducible over $F$. If $E$ is a field that contains $F$ and there is an element $a$ of $E$ such that $p(a)=0$ then show that the mapping $\phi : F[x]\rightarrow E$ given by $f(x)\rightarrow f(a)$ is ring homomorphism with kernel $\langle p(x)\rangle$

**My attempt**:

I have done homomorphism part.

clearly by hypothesis $p(x)\in \ker\phi$ and hence $\langle p(x)\rangle\subseteq \ker\phi$. Also we know that, as $p(x)$ is irreducible polynomial over a field $F$ hence $\langle p(x)\rangle$ is maximal ideal of $F[x]$. So that, by definition of maximal ideal as $\langle p(x)\rangle \subseteq \ker\phi\subseteq F[x]$ hence, $\ker\phi =\langle p(x)\rangle$ or $\ker\phi=F[x]$.

**How to conclude that**  $\ker\phi=\langle p(x)\rangle$ ? Please help.

Comment: $1 \notin \ker \phi$, so the second option is discarted.

Comment: @azif00 thank u.

Comment: You can also go the direct way. If $f(a) =0$ then $p(x) \mid f(x) $ so kernel is indeed $\langle p(x) \rangle $.